# libsvm.dll could not be added as a reference in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, libsvm

When I try to add libsvm.dll reference in VS2010 C# it reports the following error.

> A reference to '..\libsvm.dll' could not be added. Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly of COM
>   component.

How can I add this file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question!
What I did was I used [SVM.net](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/downloads/software/svm.zip) from [matthew johnson](http://www.matthewajohnson.org) website
which works fine. You can add this file to your reference and use it!!